# i didn't receive confirmation email in my Gmail account But in the server i can see confirmation link

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, devise-confirmable

Here is the log of my server. I didn't receive any confirmation message in my Gmail but in the server I found confirmation link

```
    Started POST "/users/sign_in" for ::1 at 2022-02-21 14:49:05 +0500
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"c8NHhHXHicKqOpfe0a8VZURCuYESM0PjzeldzVcgqJqOfuWH2uS8KUT/I0LRQiJQ3qNux9B5+l6h9H/pNSSzxA==", "user"=>{"email"=>"ifaheem520@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Log in"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["email", "ifaheem520@gmail.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ /home/hamid/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.6.2/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/dashboard
Completed 302 Found in 290ms (ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)


Started GET "/dashboard" for ::1 at 2022-02-21 14:49:06 +0500
Processing by HomeController#dashboard as HTML
  Rendering home/dashboard.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered home/dashboard.html.erb within layouts/application (0.3ms)
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:15
Completed 200 OK in 19ms (Views: 17.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)


Started DELETE "/users/sign_out" for ::1 at 2022-02-21 14:49:08 +0500
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#destroy as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"SnDHlGHRWTVad5WMCmMYUuHUmOOblh0jUgHHMCUlq+LVeavIRTsEUnbOocJyc1A8CJfQyqyitDugA9lESQVgFg=="}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ /home/hamid/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.6.2/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  ↳ /home/hamid/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.6.2/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
   (0.1ms)  commit transaction
  ↳ /home/hamid/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.6.2/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 8ms (ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)


Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2022-02-21 14:49:08 +0500
Processing by HomeController#homepage as HTML
  Rendering home/homepage.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered home/homepage.html.erb within layouts/application (0.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 25ms (Views: 23.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

I don't know why it's happening can anybody tell me how I can resolve this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont see that actual email has been sent from your application. Did you setup devise confirmable model correctly? Also make sure that your mailer configuried properly. In order to recieve confirmation emails you need to set up :confirmable model to your user model. Here is the instructions on how to set up :confirmable model in devise gem: https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To%3A-Add-%3Aconfirmable-to-Users

Comment: Hello Tim, would you be so kind to add a brief synopsis of the link? Its content may change over time while this question and answer remains searchable.

Comment: Hi, what kind of a brief should i add?